# Compare one csv file to multiple csv files and write new csv files R

Tags: r, loops

I am pretty new to loops in R so I do apologies if this question has been asked elsewhere.

Read in all 30 CSVfiles -> Compare File A species to the other 30 CSV files by species -> Write a new CSV file for each of the 30 files with just the matching species

File A has one column with the names of 190 species (`$name`). The 30 other csv files each have a column with the species (`$SBSname`) with differing number of species in the column `$SBSname` that can range from 100-500 with replicates (so the file CSV file can be larger than 190 rows). However I don't know how to write the code that ...

This is all I have at the moment ...

I have looped in all the CSV files:

```
30files = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(30files)) assign(30files[i], read.csv(30files[i]))
```

I have code for just comparing one CSV file (`branching.csv`) against File A:

```
> str(FileA)
'data.frame':   **190 obs. of  1 variable**:
 $ name: Factor w/ 190 levels "Acaena novae zelandiae",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

> str(branching.csv)
'data.frame':   **4055 obs. of  7 variables:**
 $ SBSname              : Factor w/ 2877 levels "Abies alba","Abies nordmanniana",..: 794 2075 1049 162 132 333 541 1840 272 1553 ...
 $ SBS.number        : int  16443 26711 40171 40398 40867 41151 37871 42412 35847 36245 ...
 $ general.method    : Factor w/ 5 levels "derivation from morphologies or other plant traits",..: 3 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ branching         : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ valid             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ reference         : Factor w/ 6 levels "Barkman, J.J.(1988): New systems of plant growth forms and phenological plant types",..: 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ original.reference: Factor w/ 97 levels "Aarssen, L.W. (1981): The biology of Canadian weeds. 50. Hypochoeris radicata L.",..: 9 9 20 3 3 3 3 3 33 33 ...

Species<-branching.csv[(branching.csv$SBSname %in% FileA$name),]
write.csv(Species, file = "Branching.csv")

> str(Species)
'data.frame':   **298 obs. of  7 variables:**
 $ name              : Factor w/ 2877 levels "Abies alba","Abies nordmanniana",..: 1049 162 1548 47 57 1647 1060 2788 2094 1976 ...
 $ SBS.number        : int  40171 40398 36280 40532 41629 42495 40103 32792 32892 30583 ...
 $ general.method    : Factor w/ 5 levels "derivation from morphologies or other plant traits",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ branching         : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ valid             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ reference         : Factor w/ 6 levels "Barkman, J.J.(1988): New systems of plant growth forms and phenological plant types",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ original.reference: Factor w/ 97 levels "Aarssen, L.W. (1981): The biology of Canadian weeds. 50. Hypochoeris radicata L.",..: 20 3 33 33 33 33 33 44 44 44 ...
```

Any help or suggestions would be great. Doesn't have to be a loop!

Comment: What do you mean by "differing number of species in the column $SBSname"? There can be duplicates of the same species in the different rows or on entry of $SBSname can have multiple (say "|" separated entries)?

Comment: So the $SBSname can have repeats of species - so duplicates of the same species in different rows

Example:
SBS name
Abutilon theophrasti
Acer campestre
Acer campestre
Acer campestre
Acer campestre
Acer campestre
Acer campestre
Acer negundo
Acer pseudoplatanus
Acer pseudoplatanus
Acer pseudoplatanus
Acer pseudoplatanus
Aceras anthropophorum
Aceras anthropophorum
Achillea millefolium

Comment: and when you say "write 30 files with just the matching species" does that mean that I should write just one column with all the (unique) species names appearing in FileA per line?

Comment: FileA has just one column of the $names with 190 species. File1 has 6 columns, one which is $names with say 300 species. If species X is present in FileA$name and present in File1$name, then to make a new CSV table with all the columns from File1. So I will be left with a new CSV file with 6 columns from File1 and 190 species as these match FileA.

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple loop?

```
library(dplyr)
for(i in 1:length(30files))
{
   csv.matching = read.csv(30files[i]) %>% inner_join(FileA, by=c("SBSname"="name"))
   write.csv(csv.matching, file=gsub("\\.csv", "_matchin.csv", 30files[i]), na="")
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this code! Not sure if it is something wrong on my end, but it only writes a CSV file for the last file in my folder. The CSV file is correct though - it matches my File A with the files, removing any species that don't match.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in the loop description. Try now